# Python lookup list of values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionary pairs created from `pyodbc` results that look something like

```
results1 = [{'TextID': u'12345', 'RecID': 10203040},{'TextID': u'54321', 'RecID': 12131415}]
results2 = [{'TextID': u'55555', 'RecID': 98979654},{'TextID': u'78909', 'RecID': 78978978}]
```

First list containing about 60000 items, second list containing about 15000 items.

From an `arcpy` cursor I am wanting to lookup the values in the two lists based on 2 existing fields from the cursor.  The dataset used by the cursor has about 50000 records.

```
for row in cursor:
    row[2] = results1.lookup(row[0])
    row[3] = results2.lookup(row[1])

cursor.updateRow(row)
```

where `row[2] = results1.lookup(row[0])` is looking up the `TextID` in my `results1` list/dict and returning the `RecID` from the dictionary pair.  The value in `row[0]` contains the `TextID` for a record in `results1`, the value in `row[1]` contains the `TextID` for a record in `results2`.

**My Question:**  What is a quick way to lookup values in dictionaries (or lists of dictionaries) based on a value from a cursor?

---

**UPDATE:**
So I managed to get my cursor looking up the list of dictionaries, but it's incredibly slow (I guess because it's looping through the entire list for every item in my cursor).

```
for row in cursor:
    if not row[0] == None:
        for a in results1:
            if not a['TextID'] == None:
                if row[0] in a['TextID']:
                    #row[2] = a['RecID']
                    print "\t",row[0], a['TextID'], a['RecID']
                    #cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Basically my list of dictionaries looks like

```
results1 = [{'TextID': u'74409', 'RecID': 10203040},{'TextID': u'75392', 'RecID': 12131415}]
```

and my cursor looks like:

```
cursor = [[u'75392', u'168569', None, None],[u'75392', u'168570', None, None],[u'68780', u'168571', None, None],[u'75392', u'168575', None, None],[u'68777', u'168586', None, None],[u'74409', u'168618', None, None],[u'68346', u'168663', None, None],[u'72926', u'168815', None, None],[u'72928', u'168849', None, None],[u'65802', u'168856', None, None]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it looks like you just want the python code to lookup the textID's, right? The following would solve that.
I hope this is what you want (I'm completely ignoring your arcpy, pyodbc etc stuff).
It runs in about 0.3 seconds here, so it should be fast enough.
    import random

```
#The results class
class results:
    def __init__(self, results):
        #textIDDict is a generated dict to speed up the lookup
        self.textIDDict={row["TextID"]: row["RecID"] for row in results}
        self.results=results

    def lookup(self, textID):
        try:
            return self.textIDDict[textID]
        except KeyError:
            return "---"

#Two functions to create the (random) data:        
def randStr():
    return str(int(random.random()*60000))

def genRes(n):
    return results([{"TextID":randStr(), "RecID": int(random.random()*10000)} for i in range(n)])


#Test it:
results1=genRes(60000)
results2=genRes(15000)

cursor=[[randStr(), randStr()] for i in range(50000)]

for row in cursor:
    row.append(results1.lookup(row[0]))
    row.append(results2.lookup(row[0]))
    print row
```

Or, if that complete program, that aparently does what you want is too complicated,
is this better?

```
result1dict={row["TextID"]: row["RecID"] for row in results1}
result2dict={row["TextID"]: row["RecID"] for row in results2}
for row in cursor[:10]:
    if row[0]!=None:
        try:
            row[2]=result1dict[row[0]]
        except KeyError:
            row[2]='---'
    if row[1]!=None:
        try:
            row[3]=result2dict[row[1]]
        except KeyError:
            row[3]='---'
    print row

        if row[1]!=None:
            row[3]=result1dict[row[0]]
```

Comment: sorry but I'm unsure how to use this?  I don't need to generate my lists, I already have those, I just need to look up values from one list and find them in a list of dictionaries.  Please see the update to my Question above

Comment: thanks that worked.  And I think i can see now what you were doing with your first code, but it didn't work for me when I tried at first.  I could probably make it work now though.  "is too complicated" - probably not, but an explanation on how/why it worked would have gone a long way.  thanks again.